# What is the version of OneNote included in Surface Pro 2?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-surface-pro

The Surface Pro 2 ships with a version of One Note built-in. Is it a crippled version?

Should I still get a full version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneNote is **free**.

It will probably come with the [**Windows Store App**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/onenote/9wzdncrfhvjl) version of OneNote, which has slightly less features than the [**Desktop Version**](http://www.onenote.com/download) (click "Windows Desktop" under "Also available on").

Here's a screenshot of the Windows Store version:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the Desktop version:

[image]